# Interfacing C functions with asm code at booting level?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, boot, osdev

I am following a tutorial about creating a 32bit operating system. I have managed to switch to the 32bit protected mode happily but could not get further.

Below, boot_sect.asm is the main assembly code. After switching to protected mode inside boot_sect.asm, an external C function (kmain) is called via kernel_entry.asm (calls the c function) from boot_sect.asm. The location of the C function in the ram is 0x1000000.

The kmain() is supposed to print an x on the screen. However, this does not happen. Indeed, to diagnose the code, I put an infinite while loop inside the kmain(), but the program did not hang there; instead it directly ended. I guess the files are not linked properly or there is a memory overlap problem. I could not get any further, and I am stuck at this point.

I would appreciate any idea or help to get over this step.

boot_sect.asm  (the main asm code)

```
; A boot sector that boots a C kernel in 32-bit protected mode
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x100000  ; This is the memory offset to where kernel will be loaded

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

    mov bp, 0x9000          ; stack origin.
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE          ;print that we are starting
    call print_string       ; booting from 16-bit real mode

    call load_kernel        ; Load our kernel

    call switch_to_pm       ; Switch to protected mode, from which
                            ; we will not return
    jmp $

; Include our useful , hard-earned routines
%include "print/print_string.asm"
%include "disk/disk_load.asm"
%include "pm/gdt.asm"
%include "pm/print_string_pm.asm"
%include "pm/switch_to_pm.asm"

[bits 16]

; load_kernel
load_kernel:
    mov bx, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL ; Print a message to say we are loading the kernel
    call print_string

    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET   ; Set-up parameters for our disk_load routine , so
    mov dh, 15              ; that we load the first 15 sectors (excluding
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]    ; the boot sector) from the boot disk (i.e. our
    call disk_load          ; kernel code) to address KERNEL_OFFSET

    ret

[bits 32]

BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE  ; Use 32-bit print routine to
    call print_string_pm    ; announce its in protected mode
            ;the program manages to come here perfectly.        
            ;here the kmain() function is called via kernel_entry.asm 
            ;but after this call, the program gets "lost", it ends somehow.
            call KERNEL_OFFSET

            ;it cant even get here, it ends before getting here. Probably        the kmain() is not located at KERNEL_OFFSET due to a problem.  
    jmp $                   ;Hang.

; Global variables
BOOT_DRIVE      db 0
MSG_REAL_MODE   db "Started in 16-bit Real Mode", 0
MSG_PROT_MODE   db "Successfully landed in 32-bit Protected Mode", 0
MSG_LOAD_KERNEL db "Loading kernel into memory.", 0

; Bootsector padding
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

kernel.c  (c code)

```
void kmain()
{
    char* screen = (char*)0xb8000;
        screen[0] = 'X';
}
```

kernel_entry.asm  (calls the c code)

```
[bits 32]
[extern _kmain]

call _kmain

jmp $
```

Finally, to obtain the os-image , I used the following commands

kernel.c and kernel_entry.asm are converted to object files (nasm and gcc commands), then they are linked to create kernel.bin file (by using ld command and the address 0x100000 of the kmain()).

Then kernel.bin and  boot_sect.bin are combined using type command to obtain an os image.

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o

ld -m i386pe -T NUL -o kernel.bin -Ttext-segment 0x100000 kernel_entry.o   kernel.o

nasm boot_sect.asm -f bin -o boot_sect.bin

type boot_sect.bin kernel.bin > os-image
```

Comment: Before developing an OS, I suggest you learn debugging. You omitted important details such as whether your GDT is an identity map or what's up with the IDT and interrupts. Also, VGA text memory requires an attribute byte as well, maybe you are printing black on black.

Comment: Thanks Jester,It does not print even come to the printing stage, the kmain() function is not executed. I am sure on this because previously I tried putting a while(1) inside it , but it did not wait just ended.

Comment: I don't think you loaded your kernel correctly at all. `mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET` ... you realize `KERNEL_OFFSET` does not fit into 16 bits, right? `nasm` should have told you that `warning: word data exceeds bounds`

Comment: that makes a lot of sense and thank you first of all. but how can I "mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET" there since all that portion is 16 bit. I cant use ebx right?

Comment: You could, but it's probably not what your `disk_load` expects. In any case, your `KERNEL_OFFSET` is outside of real mode addressing (you don't seem to have A20 enabled) so you won't be able to load there.

Comment: I enabled warnings, and "boot_sect.asm:35: warning: word data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]" is the only warning nasm gives.

Comment: @Egeözgül as others already pointed out, that means that it get loaded somewhere else than where you actually jump.

Comment: I learned that it is possible to use the es register to point to the far adress levels. In my case, if it is possible, how can I point the bx register to 0x100000 by using the es register?

Comment: Even with segmentation, you need to enable A20 to get access to that memory, and even then, only barely. Also, your `disk_load` that you didn't show must be prepared to take `es:bx`. Anyway, read up on real mode addressing.

Comment: @Jester : (I assume by barely you allude to maximum linear address addressable in real mode) 10FFEF Usually if you want to use the BIOS to do disk reads above 1mb, you'd enable A20, setup unreal mode, use the BIOS disk read loading into lower memory and then copy what is read in low memory to the region >= 0x100000 using 32-bit memory operands. This will allow you to read large amounts of code/data above the 1mb mark.